# fstream error in compiler C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, compiler-errors, fstream

This is a real newbie question but my compiler is giving me the error:

```
std::fstream has no member named getc
```

It is relative to this line of code:

```
char ch;

for ((ch=fpin.getc());!fpin.eof();(ch=fpin.getc()))
```

fpin is a file and I have checked for opening etc. it's fine. I'm also not worried about the quality of the code, just worried about getting it to work. I've been staring at it so long that I can't see the problem.

Comment: There is no ifstream::getc method, so you shouldn't call it. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream).

Comment: That's because it doesn't have a member named `getc`

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys. I really should know this stuff at this stage!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What djechlin said, but if you do want to get by character you can do `ch = fpin.get()`, which will grab a single character. or you can do `fpin >> ch;` to get a single character but ignore whitespace.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks for that will accept answer when I can. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The method you are trying to call is `std::fstream::get`. You can read about `std::fstream` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream).

Answer (score 3):

Well, the compiler is right, `getc()` is not a method on `ifstream`.  Here are your options:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream

usually

```
while(std::getline(myInStream, sstr)) 
{ 
    // ... 
}
```

is what you want.